# What does `apt-get -b source <prog-name>` do exactly?

Tags: compiling

It downloads source and patches, then what ? How can someone build the downloaded source just as the apt-get does manually ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apt-get -b` alone doesn't do anything, it has to be used in conjunction with two other options.

1. Run `sudo apt-get build-dep <prog_name>` to build dependencies for the program first
2. Run `sudo apt-get -b source <prog_name>` to actually download the source code and build it.

In my test just now with `nano` text editor, after running `sudo apt-get build-dep nano` and then `sudo apt-get -b source nano`, apt actually ran make file to compile all `*.c` source files and then `deb-buildpackage` to actually build the deb package for installation.

Comment: oh thanks. I can't believe it only runs make file